# Export password protected PDF from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, password

Is there a way to export a map as a PDF so that it is immediately read-only? Or generally protected? I want to do this in QGIS, so that I can directly export an PDF that is protected.

I didn't find any settings in QGIS.

Comment: You could prevent alterations by exporting the map as raster data only, but that wouldn't suite our use case and reduce the map quality when zoomed in.

Comment: you can use a print driver like cutepdf to create a password protected pdf.